# Upload multiple files to Parse server with a single request

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to upload multiple files to my Parse server, each one of them in a different row in the class.

I know i could use the static ParseObject method saveAllInBackground to upload all the rows in a single request, but according to [Parse's guide](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/android/guide/#files) i would need to save each ParseFile separately before i put it in a ParseObject and i want to try to minimize the saving requests.

So i wish to figure out 3 things:

1. Is there a way to upload the files on a single request?
2. If not possible, wouldn't it be problematic to insert a row when the ParseFile saveInBackground method haven't finished?
3. If possible, is there a way to update a progress bar to show the upload progress of ALL the files instead of a single one each time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the answers for your questions are:

1. No you cannot but you can execute multiple requests to the server in parallel
2. Yes because the file was not already created and in order to have a valid file the PFFile must be uploaded and a URL must be available so you need to wait until the PFFile is uploaded and then attach it.
3. There is no such feature but i faced the same situation one month ago and what i did was to keep a private variable (you can call it **progressSum** or something else) and inside each one of the progress callbacks you add the progress value to this sum (progressSum += progressValue) and then when the value is equal to the number of uploaded files you know that you done.

Comment: Thanks, i will do that. about the question 2, when i upload many rows each containing a file with saveAllInBackground() it saves them all (70+) at the same second, although Back4App limits to 30 req/s.